# Text based adventure game inventory problems python

Tags: python, python-2.7, inventory

I have been working on a horror texted based adenture game & I am having some inventory problems. The inventory is an array that I can call in any function. I kind of got there but am just repopulating my array with a new inventory every time. I could use some help, these are my inventory functions:

```
#Populating an aray with items to be used throughout the game.
def createItems():
   items = range(0, 11)
   if items[9] != "full":
      items[1] = ("Axe")
      items[2] = ("Gas")
      items[3] = ("keys")
      items[4] = ("gun")
      items[5] = ("note")
      items[9] = ("full")
      return items
   else:
      return items 
# this function is going to check if the item passed to it is still in the array
def checkItems(item):
  list = createItems()
  itemC = item
  for i in range (0, 11):
    if list[i] == itemC:
      return ("no")
      break

def createInventory():
   inv = range(0 , 11)
   inv[10] = ("made")
   if inv[10] != ("made"):
      for i in range (0, 11):
         inv[i] = 0
   return inv

def stockInventory(item):
  inv = createInventory()
  for i in range (0, 11):
     if inv[i] == 0:
       inv[i] = item 
       break
       return inv

def checkInventory(item):
    itemC = item
    inv = createInventory()
    for i in range(0, 11):
       if itemC == inv[i]:
          return ("yes")
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly, this is impossible to follow.

Comment: Just did sorry about that @DanielRoseman

Comment: It's going to be hard to answer because there are four or five really fundamental misunderstandings in this code. I suggest you look at sections 1-5 of http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/ and then come back to this...

Comment: Can you name a couple, It almost works. I am just having a slight problem with getting to the inventory after it has stuff in it. @MrE

Comment: You should really study [python lists](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)

Comment: 1) `checkInventory` calls `createInventory` which means you are returning a new inventory each time rather than storing it in a variable and passing it as an argument. 2) you call `return` straight after `break` (i.e. you'll never hit the `return` statement), similarly `break` after `return`, 3) how to construct a list of strings 4) setting `inv[10]` to a value and then immediately checking what that value is...

Comment: Alright thanks, this is the last project I have to do with python then i'm done with it. So I could make a list like items = [ stuff, stuff ] then call it with *args? sound right? Then i wont have to cycle through the arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the answer, but from what I could make out from the code & the question, this should help. Note the differences in your code & mine & make changes accordingly.

```
# Main Inventory
Inventory = createInventory()

# Populating given inventory aray with items to be used throughout the game.
def createItems(inv):
    items = inv
    items[1] = "Axe"
    items[2] = "Gas"
    items[3] = "keys"
    items[4] = "gun"
    items[5] = "note"
    items[9] = "full"

# Check if the item passed to it is still in the inventory array
def checkItems(item):
    items = Inventory
    for i in range(len(items)):
        if items[i] == item:
            return "yes"
    return "no"

def createInventory():
    inv = range(11)
    inv[10] = "made"
    return inv

def stockInventory(item):
    inv = Inventory
    for i in range (11):
        if inv[i] == 0:
            inv[i] = item
            break
    return inv

def checkInventory(item):
    inv = Inventory
    for i in range(0, 11):
        if item == inv[i]:
            return "yes"
    return "no"
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. I didn't know python supported global variables. Bad teacher...

Comment: Check this out - http://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python

Answer (score 0):

You could make make inventory into a boolen value.

```
inventory = {"sword":True, "axe":True}
```

It would also help to make classes for your inventory.

```
class Weapon():

    def attack(self, monster):
        pass

class Axe(Weapon):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "axe"
        self.damage = 1

    def attack(self, monster):
        monster.hp -= self.damage
```